# Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles Now Available, but the account is empty

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Today I was happy to receive this email from Apple. I'm a member of 3 teams but one of them was totally wiped out:

- no more devices
- no more certificates
- no more provisioning profiles
- no appIDs

I'm not worried about cert and devices, but I'm warried about the appID, yesterday I've submitted an app to the appstore, with an appID that doesn't exist anymore!!!!!! 
Am I the only one with that problem? Does someone know if there could be a problem in the review and releasing process?
[image]

Comment: same issue here! im not event allowed to refresh my certificates in the organiser

Comment: sorry to know that but on the dev portal, I have everything intact as it was before...!!

Comment: Upvote the question, so most of people with the same issue can see it. Now I sent a bug throught the bug reporte and contacted Apple from the contact form. On monday I will call them,

Comment: @samfisher thx for you feedback, I think is just an issue for few devs, my other teams are intact.

Comment: @T.Baba pls send a bug throught the bug reporter to Apple the more we the faster will fix that issue. https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn

Comment: I was able to recreate my identity including a private key (which requires CSR), and all provisions from within the portal. All (valid and expired) provisions and certificates, and all devices were there. So it seems, the portal is working. However, I was not able to do anything from within Xcode: all attempts to access the server timed out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Apple Developer site.

Answer (score 2):

About 10 hours ago, I received an e-mail message titled 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles Now Available' for both Mac OS developer account and iOS developer account.  I waited for 8 long days so that I could submit two **OS X** software titles.  Finally, I was able to create app identifiers.  Then I learnt that **iTunes Connect** did not read new app ID additions.  I was as furious as an atomic bomb.  What I did was clicked on **contact us** and told them about the problem I faced.  After waiting for a couple of hours, the problem was fixed, and I was able to submit applications to iTunes Connect.

What I'm telling is not exactly a fix.  And I don't know if the problem was a propagation issue, or they actually fixed something upon my message.  But if you haven't, I would click on that 'contact us' contact them.  Also, I wrote to them through iTunes Connect's Contact us.

[image]

Comment: Hi TBlue I did contact Apple, Let's see what's happen